# PHP or ASP, which should I stick to?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have worked almost for a year now on PHP. I was using C# for my academic projects. But, I am getting offers to switch to ASP.NET/C# these days. Would leaving my current platform be fruitful? My familiarity with open source technologies is deep and I couldn't decide what I should do with these offers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends on how people answer it - trolls aside, it's a decent question.

Comment: You could either try http://phalanger.codeplex.com/ (PHP compiler for .net) Or give more detail about where you would like to go in the world... for instance if you'd like to be a serious contributor to the php project, asp.net wont help etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is nothing wrong with being good at both - PHP is favored in open-environments (LAMP stacks, etc) and ASP.NET is a great enterprise platform. So, if you tried to learn .NET it would only strengthen your resume/skillset. And perhaps your wallet. ;)

Comment: thanks @BenHayden and all for feedbacks.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to all these subjective questions "is xxx better than yyy" is always the same:

**It's not a wand, it's a wizard**

Period.

Particular platform or language are matter only for *a coder*, not for *a programmer.*
A real programmer thinks algorithms and architecture, not operators of single language.
Once algorithm is done, particular operators doesn't that matter.
And a programmer chooses proper *tool* for the certain task, not "more fruitful" trend.

So, grow up, learn how *to program*.

Comment: But coding is always part of programmers job. So if in one language you can build simple abstraction layers, then coding is easier and you can bring more attention to programming

Answer (score 1):

I love open-source because they have great community and a lot of affection, **PHP**  will be my choice.

Comment: -1 choosing something just because is open source is a very wrong way of living !

Comment: @balexandre: I think not in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that you'd get deep familiarity with some technology in a year. Both of these technologies are widely used today, your best bet would be to look at the job offers in your area and see for yourself which one would be advantageous to specialize in further.